# BrowserRouter inside component called by top level BrowserRouter with NavLinks falls out of sync

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When a user navigates using `<Header>` NavLinks or browser buttons, the `<Progression>` component's BrowserRouter children ignore the change.

That is to say, if a user has loaded the `<Progression>` component, and clicks the /progression NavLink to return to `<Progression>`'s entry point, nothing happens as the match happens on the top level BrowserRouter.

[image]

I've tried moving the `<Header>` component into `<Progression>` component's Router, and this fixes it wonderful until a user attempts to navigate outside of the component i.e. away from the `<Progression>` component as its BrowserRouter doesn't have any of the routes for other pages unlike its top level parent.

Am I using BrowserRouter correctly, or is there a better, easier way, to achieve this?

How do I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add asyncComponent:

```js
//asyncComponent.js
import React, {Component} from 'react'

const asyncComponent = (importComponent) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            component: null
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            importComponent().then((cmp) => {
                this.setState({component: cmp.default})
            })
        }

        render() {
            const C = this.state.component
            return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : null
        }
    }
}

export default asyncComponent

//App.js

const asyncComp = asyncComponent(() => {
    return import('../containers/component/myComponent')
})

<Route path={'/path/:id'} component={asyncComp} />
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what this does, but I presume I'd need to pass all my top level routes' components through it?

Answer (score 0):

It was posed to me that I shouldn't use more than one BrowserRouter, so I moved as many routes to the top level as I could. I wasn't doing this originally in an attempt to keep my code more manageable.

Unfortunately, I still need and use a BrowserRouter in one of my components, which works great except for one `<Link />` that links to a top level route. I haven't worked out what I'll do with it yet, but if I do, I'll edit and share.